# Recording stream via RTMP Android

Tags: java, android, websocket, rtmp

I am streaming via RTMP protocol with Web Socket. I need to record this stream with sound and save as mp4 file locally. Any ideas?

I've tried FFmpegKit library but it fails after executing

FFmpeg command:

```
FFmpegKit.executeAsync("-i" + "rtmp://someurl" + "-c:v copy -c:a copy" + targetFile, session -> {
    com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.SessionState mState = session.getState();
    ReturnCode returnCode = session.getReturnCode();
    
    Log.d("TAG", String.format("FFmpeg process exited with state %s and rc %s.%s", mState, returnCode, session.getFailStackTrace()));
});
```

After executing the command, I get the following error:

> Server error: RTMP playback is disabled. Operation not permitted.

[image]